# Matplotlib: multiple lines plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Bin           A      B      C   Proba-a%   Proba-b%   Proba-c%    gamma%
CPB%                                                                    
0.100     20841  23195  24546  34.503457  27.103303  22.859837     0.100
0.200      2541   4187   5176  26.517913  13.944499   6.593338     0.200
0.300      2750   1823   1122  17.875550   8.215217   3.067253     0.300
0.400       999    829    448  14.736015   5.609856   1.659334     0.400
0.500       604    495    217  12.837838   4.054181   0.977373     0.500
0.600       436    348    116  11.467630   2.960495   0.612822     0.600
0.700       367    247     76  10.314268   2.184230   0.373979     0.700
0.800       305    186     35   9.355751   1.599673   0.263985     0.800
0.900       280    115     24   8.475801   1.238254   0.188561     0.900
1.000       200    102     18   7.847266   0.917691   0.131992     1.000
```

what I would like to do is to have on the x axis 'gamma%' and a chart with three lines A, B and C. I saw somewhere that you had to call multiple time plt, I tried that:

```
plt.plot(x='gamma%', y='A', data=df_b)
plt.plot(x='gamma%', y='B',data=df_b)
plt.plot(x='gamma%', y='C',data=df_b)
```

But I had the following error:

```
ValueError: Using arbitrary long args with data is not supported due to ambiguity of arguments.
Use multiple plotting calls instead.
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your method is fine, just dont explicitly say `x='gamma%'`. Instead just pass the column name like `'gamma%'` and it should work

**Example :**

```
plt.plot('gamma%', 'A', data=df_b)
```

Here it is directly from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) :

> **Plotting labelled data**
>
> There's a convenient way for plotting objects with labelled data (i.e.
>   data that can be accessed by index obj['y']). Instead of giving the
>   data in x and y, you can provide the object in the data parameter and
>   just give the labels for x and y:
>
> > `plot('xlabel', 'ylabel', data=obj)`

Comment: Maybe worth noting that `plt.scatter(x='gamma%', y='A', data=df_b)` would work just fine. The reason is that `x` and `y` are named arguments for `scatter`, but not for `plot`. Also consider that the same plot could be achieved in a single line, `df_b.set_index("gamma%")[["A","B","C"]].plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use your DataFrame to plot the three columns in a looped manner without having to write three separate plot commands as follows

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for cols in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    df_b.plot('gamma%', cols, ax=ax)
```

[image]