# Matplotlib: How to plot multiple lines on one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know there's many questions about this (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233996/matplotlib-multiple-lines-plot)), I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I have this data:

```
Prod T1 T2
A  0  4
B  0  6.7
C  0  8.8
D  0  6.8
E  0  6.75
F  0  7.8
G  0  33.5
H  0  21
```

I want the plot to have 8 lines (A-H), each line showing growth from time period 1 (T1) to time period 2 (T2).

I wrote this code:

```
# libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Data
df=pd.DataFrame({'Product':['A','B','C', 'D','E','F','G','H'], 'Time Period 2': ['4','6.7','8.8','6.8','6.75','7.8','33.5','21.00']})

# multiple line plot
plt.plot('Product','Time Period 2',data=df,marker='o',color='orange',linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

The output is each product (A-H) on the x axis and the T2 numbers on the Y axis:

[image]

But what I want is for each product to have it's own growth line from T1 to T2 (e.g. like this example from the internet):

[image]

Can someone show me how to change this so the X axis just has two values 'time 1' and time 2', then there are multiple lines (A-H), showing growth from T1 to T2 (so e.g. for A, the T1 y value is 0 and the T2 y value is 4).

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to add .plots and they will be added on the same graph, for example you can do this:

```
# libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Data
df=pd.DataFrame({'Product':['A','B','C', 'D','E','F','G','H'], 'Time Period 2': 
['4','6.7','8.8','6.8','6.75','7.8','33.5','21.00']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Product':['A','B','C', 'D','E','F','G','H'], 'Time Period 3': 
['12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19']})

# multiple line plot
plt.plot('Product','Time Period 2',data=df,marker='o',color='orange',linewidth=2)
plt.plot('Product','Time Period 3',data=df2,marker='o',color='orange',linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that can help you or if i understood the question, but i did that :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
y2 = [4,6.7,8.8,6.8,6.75,7.8,33.5,21]

fig= plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.title("title")
plt.xlabel("xlabel")
plt.ylabel("ylabel")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

[Here is the result I had :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DDJV.png)